# Pie Crust Partially Cooked

Tags: pie

I was given a pie at a food bank,it is not out of date, how ever, when I cut the pie the bottom crust was raw, how can I fix this, can I bake it for awhile, I need an answer, I really don't want to throw it away, It is a Pineapple Upside Down Pie, it looks really delicious.

Answer (score 1):

Either eat everything but the crust, or consider placing pie & dish onto a skillet/pan to apply heat to the pie crust.

Note: as the pie is cut, the filling or any sugars may liquefy and seep into the crust and potentially burn.

Answer (score 1):

You could bake the whole pie. If you have a pizza stone, preheat that in the oven before you put your pie inside. Cover your pie tightly with foil to keep the top from burning. The foil will also help the keep the pie from drying out.